# Python 3, add two dictionaries and adding item inside the list associated with a key both dictionaries have

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, dictionary

I have a long list of names with work/hours but there are given based on locations.

For example:

Giving : LOCATION, NAME, MON, TUES, WED, THURS, FRI

```
for rows in  data:
    print(rows)
```

This prints:

```
"location_1", "name_1", "0.0","0.0","0.0","4.1","2.2"
"location_2", "name_1", "8.0","8.0","8.0","0.0","3.0"
"location_1", "name_2", "8.4","7.3","7.2","4.0","2.0"
"location_1", "name_3", "7.0","7.0","5.0","6.0","3.0"
```

If you notice the first 2 row has the same name but different locations, I would like to combine them into one dict by adding their values.
i can make them into dictionaries like this one. (pay attention to name_1 and how will be modify)

```
location_1= {"name_1":["0.0","0.0","0.0","4.1","2.2"],
             "name_2":["8.4","7.3","7.2","4.0","2.0"],
             "name_3":["7.0","7.0","5.0","6.0","3.0"]}

location_2 = {"name_1":["8.0","8.0","8.0","0.0","3.0"]}
```

but i need add the two dictionaries by adding the values of the list associated with the keys with the same name. so the result should look like this (notice the last value of name_1 and how the last value was add for the previous dict):

```
result_dict = {"name_1":["8.0","8.0","8.0","4.1","5.2"],
               "name_2":["8.4","7.3","7.2","4.0","2.0"],
               "name_3":["7.0","7.0","5.0","6.0","3.0"]}
```

I'm new in Python so if anyone can show me an efficient way to do this, it will be great. 
Thank you.

Comment: what happens if there are numbers for the same day, like 3.0 and 2.0 for monday ?

Comment: the should be add together , thank you for your question.

Comment: why are the numbers in string format? is that necessary?

Comment: It's not necessary. I'm new to programing, i didnt realize this could be a problem, now i can see it, thank you for you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy using a 3rd party library, you can do this easily with `numpy`.

I have intentionally kept the output in numeric form. It is good practice to store numeric data in numeric types.

```
import numpy as np

d1= {"name_1":["0.0","0.0","0.0","4.1","2.2"],
     "name_2":["8.4","7.3","7.2","4.0","2.0"],
     "name_3":["7.0","7.0","5.0","6.0","3.0"]}

d2 = {"name_1":["8.0","8.0","8.0","0.0","3.0"]}

res = {k: np.array(d1.get(k, [0]*5), dtype=float) + \
          np.array(d2.get(k, [0]*5), dtype=float) \
       for k in d1.keys() | d2.keys()}

# {'name_1': array([ 8. ,  8. ,  8. ,  4.1,  5.2]),
#  'name_2': array([ 8.4,  7.3,  7.2,  4. ,  2. ]),
#  'name_3': array([ 7.,  7.,  5.,  6.,  3.])}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't need any external libraries, so might be easier if you're not familiar with Python.

```
location_1= {"name_1":["0.0","0.0","0.0","4.1","2.2"],
                       "name_2":["8.4","7.3","7.2","4.0","2.0"],
                       "name_3":["7.0","7.0","5.0","6.0","3.0"]}
location_2 = {"name_1":["8.0","8.0","8.0","0.0","3.0"]}
```

.

```
for key, value in location_2.items():
    if key not in location_1:
        location_1[key] = value
    else:
        for i in range(len(value)):  # each index in the list
            old = location_1[key][i]
            new = float(old)+float(value[i])
            location_1[key][i] = str(new)  # str optional
```

At the end, the value is converted back into a string, but I would recommend keeping it as a numerical value.

Also, a float stores a floating point number, which can have decimal places, and can be manipulated as a number rather than a string, if you're new to general coding. To leave the value as a float, replace the last line

```
    location_1[key][i] = str(new)
```

with

```
    location_1[key][i] = new
```

Comment: +1 for a working solution. But note, a `float` is not `Decimal` in Python. They are 2 distinct types. Python has a separate `Decimal` library. Internally, floats are stored in base2, not base10.